# Scala: cannot resolve method error for case class in pattern matching

Tags: scala

I try to reimplement again Some and None in scala for learning purpose. I do all of following code in scala workspace.

```
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]

trait Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))   // error here
  }
}
```

I meet following error:

> Cannot resolve method name unapply

I don't understand this. Because this error often happens in normal class only. Please tell me why I meet this error.

Comment: Works perfectly fine in the REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the interpreter is just confused, because it imports behind the scene the following:

- `scala._`
- `java.lang._`
- `scala.Predef._`

These include the `Option` class and its subtypes - `Some` and `None`. I've just renamed your classes a bit and everything works fine:

```scala
trait Optional[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Optional[B] = this match {
    case Absent => Absent
    case Present(a) => Present(f(a))
  }
}
case class Present[+A](get: A) extends Optional[A]
case object Absent extends Optional[Nothing]

Present(3).map(_ * 2) // Present(6)
```